# What does operation mean in jmh?

Tags: java, jmh

In the jmh results, the score is in ns/op, the time spent in nanoseconds per operation, does operation refer to the benchmark call?
If that is the case a lower score would mean a faster call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is the time spent executing your benchmark method: the smaller the number the faster it was. This is also explained in the javadoc of the [different modes](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/7e1c1c40872d/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Mode.java) - looking at `AverageTime`:

> Runs by continuously calling Benchmark methods, counting the average time to call over all worker threads. [...]

Note that there are other modes, such as throughput, which gives you the number of invocations per time unit - in that mode, the larger the number the faster the method.